# UnitTesting Elasticsearch.net IElasticLowLevelClient

Tags: c#, unit-testing, elasticsearch, moq

I have a very simple class that uses Elasticsearch.net to access an endpoint with a simple query. The class and method works fine and I get the expected results. But I am not successful in UnitTesting this class.
Here is the class I am trying to UnitTest:

```
namespace X
{
public class YLookup : IYLookup
{
    private readonly IElasticLowLevelClient _lowLevelClient;
    public YLookup()
    {

    }
    public YLookup(IElasticLowLevelClient lowLevelClient)
    {
        _lowLevelClient = lowLevelClient;
    }

    public string Lookup(string Z)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Z))
        {
            return string.Empty;
        }
        var searchResponse = _lowLevelClient.Search<StringResponse>(
            "person",
            "company",
            "My elastic search query");

        if (searchResponse.Success)
        {
            // success! Parse searchResponse.Body;
        }
        else
        {
            // Failure :(
        }
    }
}
}
```

The interface:

```
namespace X
{
internal interface IYLookup
{
    string Lookup(string Z);
}
}
```

The code I am using to try to UnitTest:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void Test1()
    {
        string h = "{\r\n\t\"took\": 2,\r\n\t\"timed_out\": false,\r\n\t\"_shards\": {\r\n\t\t\"total\": 6,\r\n\t\t\"successful\": 6,\r\n\t\t\"failed\": 0\r\n\t},\r\n\t\"hits\": {\r\n\t\t\"total\": 0,\r\n\t\t\"max_score\": null,\r\n\t\t\"hits\": []\r\n\t}\r\n}";

        Mock<IApiCallDetails> apiCallDetails = new Mock<IApiCallDetails>(MockBehavior.Strict);
        apiCallDetails.Setup(x => x.Success).Returns(true);

        Mock<ElasticsearchResponse<string>> elasticsearchResponse = new Mock<ElasticsearchResponse<string>>();
        elasticsearchResponse.Setup(x => x.Body).Returns(h);

        Mock<StringResponse> s = new Mock<StringResponse>();
        s.Setup(x => x.ApiCall).Returns(apiCallDetails.Object);

        Mock<IElasticLowLevelClient> elasticLowLevelClient = new Mock<IElasticLowLevelClient>(MockBehavior.Strict);

        elasticLowLevelClient.Setup(x => x.Search<StringResponse>(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string>(),, It.IsAny<PostData>(), It.IsAny<SearchRequestParameters>())).Returns(s.Object);
    }
```

The error I am having is:

```
invalid setup on a non-virtual (overridable in vb) member
```

I need to set the success property and the body property and I am not seeing how I can set the body with the complicated structure of the objects involved.

Does someone have a solution or can see what I am doing wrong?
Thanks.

P.S. Please ignore naming. I have changed them to these meaningless names on purpose.

Comment: At first glance I'd guess that it is the `elasticsearchResponse.Setup` or the  `s.Setup` that is failing. Can you confirm this?  If so, then these most likely the members that you are trying to setup are not virtual - cannot be mocked.  Can you just instantiate instances of them instead?

Comment: Both of them fail.
I have tried different combinations of mocking objects and instantiating them but to no avail. It really does not like to have the body property set for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From looking at the source ([Elasticsearch-net on GitHub](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/blob/22ec0199a48a29e256a0323b176fcb00b048dd76/src/Elasticsearch.Net/Responses/Special/StringResponse.cs)) you should be able to create an instance of `StringResponse` directly, passing in the `Body` in the ctor.  The `ApiCall` property on the `ElasticsearchResponseBase` has a public get/set pair so you should be able to do something along the lines of

```
[TestMethod]
public void Test1()
{
    string h = "{\r\n\t\"took\": 2,\r\n\t\"timed_out\": false,\r\n\t\"_shards\": {\r\n\t\t\"total\": 6,\r\n\t\t\"successful\": 6,\r\n\t\t\"failed\": 0\r\n\t},\r\n\t\"hits\": {\r\n\t\t\"total\": 0,\r\n\t\t\"max_score\": null,\r\n\t\t\"hits\": []\r\n\t}\r\n}";

    Mock<IApiCallDetails> apiCallDetails = new Mock<IApiCallDetails>(MockBehavior.Strict);
    apiCallDetails.Setup(x => x.Success).Returns(true);

    var resp = new StringResponse(h);
    resp.ApiCall = apiCallDetails.Object;

    Mock<IElasticLowLevelClient> elasticLowLevelClient = new Mock<IElasticLowLevelClient>(MockBehavior.Strict);

    elasticLowLevelClient.Setup(x => x.Search<StringResponse>(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<PostData>(), It.IsAny<SearchRequestParameters>())).Returns(resp);
}
```

I have copied the code from above for the lowLevelClient setup (removing the extra comma) but if we want to check that search is being invoked correctly we should match them off to the actual parameters rather than using ().

Comment: Oh. That is a bit embarassing. Somehow I did not see the constructor that took a body as a parameter. This solved it. Thanks. If nothing else comes up then I will accept this answer eventually.